# Fetch ETH price from coinmarketcap api

Tags: go-ethereum

i tried to fetch eth price from cmc in my php file.
But it's empty. I'm not an expert, only a frontend developer.
Maybe someone can review this short code. Thank you!

```
    $api_key = 'MY-API-KEY';

    $api_url    = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=USD';

  $data = file_get_contents($api_url);
  $priceInfo = json_decode($data);

  echo $priceInfo[0]->price_usd;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the endpoint is no longer being served by the coinmarketcap when I manually testing on browser. And I realized they have cloudflare firewall which even if the API is valid, your scrapper might not able to consume the API unless you are using some sort of proxy

Comment: Ah. Ok. Can you provide which link i have to use for a working output maybe with the coingecko api or with the right cmc api link? I do not find the working api link.. in this documentation. Thank you! something like this.. https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?id=1